# How to align jstree grid columns data 'right' or 'left'?

Tags: jquery, jstree, treegrid

I am working on a jsTree grid. I have successfully rendered the grid in my UI, but I want to align my column data to the right or left. I want to align NOOFBILLS to right. Below is my JS code. Please, can anyone who has knowledge about this help me out?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formid").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // to stop form being submitted because it reloads the page.
        $.ajax({
            url: "Drilldown",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#formid").hide();
                $("div#jstree").jstree({
                    plugins: ["grid", "dnd", "contextmenu", "ui", "themes", "html_data"],
            core: {
                data: data
            },
            // configure tree table
            grid: {
                columns: [{
                    width: 'auto',
                    header: "Outlet"
                }, {
                    width: 'auto',
                    value: "itemcode",
                    header: "NoOfBills"
                }, {
                    width: 'auto',
                    value: "totalAmount",
                    header: "Amount"
                }],
            resizable: true,
            width: 5000,
            height: 3000
        }
    });
 }
 });
 });
});
```

Comment: Refer documentation link https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid, where option like: **cellClass**: a CSS class to add to each cell in this column (except for the header) - added to the <span>. You can refer given link to explore more options.

Comment: @PrasadWargad bro i am not able to find any thing can you please tell me how it will be done.. i am stuck here only from2 days

Comment: Here is the https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid#options link for list of available options in jsTree. Search for a word "cellClass" you will get some clue.

Comment: @PrasadWargad  i already searched there but i don't know hot to implement that

Answer (score 0):

CSS CODE:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .aright {
        // write here your css to make text right align
    }
    .acenter {
        // write here your css to make text center align
    }
    .aleft {
        // write here your css to make text left align
    }
</style>
```

JS CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formid").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // to stop form being submitted because it reloads the page.
        $.ajax({
            url: "Drilldown",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#formid").hide();
                $("div#jstree").jstree({
                    plugins: ["grid", "dnd", "contextmenu", "ui", "themes", "html_data"],
                    core: {
                        data: data
                    },
                    // configure tree table
                    grid: {
                        columns: [{
                            width: 'auto',
                            header: "Outlet",
                            cellClass: "aright"
                        }, {
                            width: 'auto',
                            value: "itemcode",
                            header: "NoOfBills",
                            cellClass: "acenter"
                        }, {
                            width: 'auto',
                            value: "totalAmount",
                            header: "Amount",
                            cellClass: "aleft"
                        }],
                        resizable: true,
                        width: 5000,
                        height: 3000
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As per documentation link: 
https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid#options

"columns" key have option "cellClass" like the way it has other options "width" etc. So you can make use of "cellClass" option to align your cell text to right/left or center align as per requirement.

You can create classes for alignment if they are not present already.

Give a try it should work.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for it, which will help to sort out the problem.

Comment: bro problem solved.. i was using text-align which only worked for div..now i am using float:right and its working :)

Comment: Cool, you did it.